# Tomcat 9.0.13 - 404 error when running with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm in the process of learning Java Web to increase my ability with Java, but I found errors before even starting.

I have Glassfish installed, but the last time I heard someone talking about it was in 2014, so I decided to start with Tomcat.

So, I successfully installed Tomcat 9.0.13 on `/opt/tomcat`, but IntelliJ (version 2018.3.1) cannot use it (it says "*The selected directory is not a valid Tomcat home*", and if I still try it says "*Application server libraries not found*"). After googling a bit I found that people suggested to download the .tar.gz file from Apache, unpack it and use from there. IntelliJ successfully recognized it, and I started writing some code to see what would happen.

Here is where the problem **really starts**.

When I try to open `localhost:8080` (the address of the application) and the application is not running it gives the browser's 404 message, just as usual, but when the application is running it gives another 404 message, with "*Apache Tomcat/9.0.13*" written at the bottom of the message, saying that *the page cannot be found*. That happens with any page I try to open (like the home page, for example, or the application page itself).

IntelliJ, by the way, doesn't show any errors in the Server tab, the Tomcat Localhost Log tab or the Tomcat Catalina Log tab.

So, should I give permission to anyone access the `/opt/tomcat` directory, and use it from there? Or should I fix whatever is causing this in the unpacked .tar.gz from Apache (and what could be causing it)?

Here is the link to the entire log the Server tab on IntelliJ (the other tabs are blank): https://pastebin.com/rwS0nFNz

**Fresh news!**

I changed the permissions of the `/opt/tomcat` directory so anyone could access it and created a application server in IntelliJ with the directory. It went successfully, and I was not much worried, since this is just for learning. However, even with the previously working directory, it still gives me a 404 error (the *"Apache Tomcat/9.0.13"* one, not the browser's default one) in any page I want to access. What could be causing this?

Comment: Is it possible to share you project for investigation?

Comment: The entire IntelliJ project or any specific folder?

Comment: Here is the link to the compressed folder: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m9u0mQoNNCiwrOxmG-pjedH2dgtDt-m-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the application context of your web application? You can see the app context under run/debug configuration on the deployment tab. 

Use this context as a suffix to your server url.

Idea should normaly start your browser pointing to the right url after the web app has been deployed successfully.

Comment: I configured IntelliJ to automatically open Firefox with the page, but it gives me the 404 error independent on which page (the home page, the manager page or the application page, for example) I try to load.